# Importing variable to vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I need import some variable to vue component file. I am doing it this way:

```
require('imports-loader?myVar=>{test:12345}!./my-com.vue');
```

As result I get `[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "ReferenceError: myVar is not defined"`

I know about `props`, but I want pass namely a variable.

Here "my-com.vue":

```
<template>
  <div>...</div>
</template>
<script>
  console.log(myVar); // <--- here I get vue warn
  export default {
    props:['rows'],
    ...
  }
</script>
```

Importing is from here:

```
module.exports = function(params){
  return function(resolve, reject){
    resolve({
      components:{
        'my-com': require('imports-loader?myVar=>{test:12345}!./my-com.vue')
      },
      ...
    })
  }
}
```

Where I am wrong?
How it possible to import a variable to vue component file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to import this variable from?. Is it present in another `.js` file?

Answer (score 7):

you can use an `import` statement

```
<script>
  import { myVar } from './path_to_the_file'
  console.log(myVar); 
  export default {
    props:['rows'],
    ...
  }
</script>
```

make sure you use the export statement in the other file to export `myVar` like this:

```
export var myVar = 'my variable';
```

Comment: Ок, it works. Still, how can I pass a variable to vue file with the imports-loader?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna using myComponent.vue file, I was confused how to set "props" . Your solution works like a charm 
+1